# Joining & Processing In SQL Server For Large Datasets Too Slow

Tags: json, sql-server, join, large-data

We're finding that the following query takes about and hour to load 1000+ records. With more than 3 million records in table 'q' and table files f has around 2 million. Any recommendation on how to speed this up ?

```
Select 
    q.Id, vStorageId,vRootId, q.vPath, p.[FileName], 
    p.Original, p.[User],
    IsNull(p.[Size], 0) as FileSize, p.[Extension], p.Encode, 
    p.[IsPicture], p.IsUploaded, 
    (Case when p.IsDirectory=1 then GetUtcDate() else p.Time end) as [Modified],
    IsNull(p.[Created], getUTCDate()) as [Created], 
    IsNull(p.IsDirectory,0) as IsDirectory
from 
    Ques q
cross apply 
    openJson(Request,'$.created') 
        WITH([Message] nvarchar(255) '$.message',  
             [FileName] nvarchar (1024) '$.name',  
             Original nvarchar (1024) '$.name',  
             [User] nvarchar (1024) '$.user', 
             [Size] bigint '$.size',  [Extension] nvarchar (255) '$.ext',  
             Encode bit '$.encode',  [IsPicture] bit '$.picture',  
             IsUploaded bit '$.uploaded', 
             [Time] DateTime2 '$.time',  [Created] DateTime2 '$.created',  
             IsDirectory int '$.dir') p
left join 
    dbo.Files f on f.[vPath] = q.[vPath] 
                and f.[FileName] = p.[FileName] 
                and q.vStorageID = f.StorageID
where 
    topic = 'Scan' 
    and State = 4 
    and f.Id is null;
```

Comment: Upload the execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: Since the join uses a value projected from the JSON, you might try "promoting" that to a column on Ques, either using a persisted or indexed computed column.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/index-json-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks David, we’re already partially doing this (See the filters vPath and vStorageId etc ) but will investigate further... Any other hints ?

Comment: Where do columns [topic] and [State] come from? (& why no aliasing used on them?)

Comment: Thanks to those of you who contributed - as the questions above indicate, this was an involved problem. We finally addressed it by taking the JSON out into its own table, and indexing it, and changing LEFT JOIN. The result is that the scan takes a few hours now, not several weeks and incremental scans also run very quickly.